# Display list of installed apps with icon

Tags: android

I'm making an activity to display a list of the installed apps and their icons on the device.
I followed the instruction in here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon.
Then I set a ListAdapter for the ArrayList returned but all I get is this
http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8677/16010593916_0f5c237348_b.jpg
(It's my class name and activity name)
And here's the code

```
public class ShortcutsActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<PInfo> packages = getPackages();

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<PInfo>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, packages));
}

class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;     
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

}
Am I doing something wrong?
Sorry for this possibly duplicate question but I have searched for answers but I can't seem to know what to do after getting the ArrayList since I'm a newbie to Android and there's still a lot to learn.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download the sample application from here https://github.com/javatechig/Advance-Android-Tutorials/tree/master/ListInstalledApps

Answer (score 0):

Currently in your TextView (I am guessing your android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 contains a TextView) you are probably setting the Text to your PInfo object .toString().

As your custom class does not override the toString()-Method Android/Java does not know what to display, and displays the default implementation which is this:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

To make the listitem show your info you have to override the toString()-Method in PInfo:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return appname + ", " + pname + ", " + versionName + "(" + versionCode + ")";
}
```

This is of course just an example and only the first step to achieving a nice layout.

According to the official Java Documentation your toString()-Method should to the following:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Comment: Thanks but I think android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is just a kind of resource the SDK generate since I didn't make any layout for this activity. Do you know how I can display the app's icon next to app's name? I mainly need the icon and the name

Comment: To do that you need to write your own implementation if the ArrayAdapter and override the getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) Method. There are hundreds of tutorials on this topic online. Just google for keywords like ListView and Adapter